# Inverse of a matrix

Tags: tensors

I am looking for a way to derive that the inverse of a matrix using Levi-Civita. I know that the final result looks like this for a $3 \times 3$ matrix:
$$(A^{-1})_{ij} = \frac{1}{2!}\frac{1}{\det A} \varepsilon_{imn} \varepsilon_{jpq} a_{pm} a_{qn}$$ 
Also, if I know that there exists a matrix of this form, how do I show that this is indeed the inverse ? I tried showing that $AA^{-1}=I=A^{-1}A$, but I got stuck in the process.

Comment: Perhaps math.stackexchange might be a better place for this question?

Comment: What does $\epsilon_{imn}$ mean?

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking here? If you are not sure about the symbol, which I highly doubt is the case, $\epsilon_{imn}$ is Levi-Civita tensor with $imn$ as index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

1. Prove that a [cofactor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_%28linear_algebra%29) $C_{k}{}^{\ell}$ of an $n\times n$ matrix $A=(a^i{}_j)_{1\leq i,j\leq n}$ is given by the formula
   $$C_{k}{}^{\ell}~=~ \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\sum_{1\leq i_2,\ldots, i_n,j_2,\ldots, j_n\leq n}\varepsilon_{ki_2\ldots i_n}~\varepsilon^{\ell j_2\ldots j_n}\prod_{r=2}^n a^{i_r}{}_{j_r}, $$
   where $\varepsilon_{i_1\ldots i_n}$ denotes the [Levi-Civita symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol).
2. Next assume that the matrix $A$ is invertible.
3. Finally apply [Cramer's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule)
   $$(A^{-1})^{\ell}{}_{k}=\frac{C_{k}{}^{\ell}}{\det(A)}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your response. At this point, I have proved the relation for cofactor. Also, I got the relation that if A is the cofactor then '$A_{ik}a_{ij} = Det A \times \delta_{kj}$'

Comment: I don't see how Cramer's rule helps me here. Can you elaborate please ?